# Best was to fill columns that are missing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to add missing values into a pandas dataframe without consuming much computational power. Below is an example :
What I am trying to achieve is. Every week should have all the three types "N,O,D". If it does not we need to fill is and add a 0 in rev.
for example: week 1 of october 2022 does not have type O and D, so I need to find a way to insert
two rows.
below two images show what is the input data and what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

after processing the data should look like :

[image]

Here is the piece of code i wrote:

```
n = df.loc[df["type"] == 'N']
d = df.loc[df["type"] == 'D']
o = df.loc[df["type"] == '0']
df_m=pd.merge(n, d, on=['wmy'], how='outer')
df_m2=pd.merge(df_m , o, on=['wmy'], how='outer')
cols = [col for col in df_m2.columns if 'type' in col]
for i in cols:
   df_m2[i]=df_m2[i].dropna().unique()[0]
df_m2 = df_m2.fillna(0)
n1=df_m2[['wmy','type_x_x','rev_x_x']]
n1.rename(columns = {'type_x_x':'type','rev_x_x':'rev'}, inplace = True )
```

...

then concatenated three dataframes

Comment: I typically handle this problem by creating a multiindex from a product of all the possible rows you would like to have, setting the index, then reindexing, then resetting the index again. Does that help?

Comment: If not, please add your data in a reproducible format

Comment: I have tried to separate the dataframe into 3 for each type. Then merged the data with week_month_year, then used fillna to fill it with the required data. Then created 3 dataframes again and concatenated them. Its a long code, so wanted to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

The below code got me what I wanted

```
result = df.pivot_table(index=['wmy'], columns='type', values='rev', fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create one more df and apply do outer join:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame([(k, val) for k,v in {s:['N','O','D'] for s in set(df['wmy'])}.items() for val in v],
         columns=['wmy','type']), how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi @Trunk please above solution might help.